# How can we add wrapper,container in meteor through jade and coffescript?

Tags: meteor, pug, stylus

I am newbie in meteor and I am trying to build simple website. Now we can define header,container in jade by simple doing it:

```
!!!5
html
  head
    title #{title} - helloworld
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    header
      h1 helloworld
    .container
      .main-content
        block content
      .sidebar
        block sidebar
    footer
      p Running on node with Express, Jade and Stylus
```

But in meteor we do by:

```
head
  title helloworld
body
  {{> hello}}



template(name="hello")
p this is helloworld
```

Now my question is how can we define container, main-content in meteor ??

Thank You in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Your `index.html` and `whatever_template.html` are just html.
You can put any containers in that html and your handlebars in those.

So you could do:

index.html

```
head
  title helloworld
body
  .container
    {{> hello}}
```

hello.html

```
template(name="hello")
.another-container
  p this is helloworld
```

Which would give you something like:

```
head
  title helloworld
body
  .container
    .another-container
      p this is helloworld
```

(Disclaimer: I've never used Jade and I'm new to meteor too (but then again, who isn't) :)